# На языке C аналог print() из python или console.log() из js с автоматическим определением передаваемых типов данных, кто-то пробовал реализовать?

Tags: c

На языке C аналог print() из python или console.log() из js с автоматическим определением передаваемых типов данных, кто-то пробовал реализовать ???

Comment: Такое есть только в C++: [`fmt::print`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#_CPPv4IDpEN3fmt5printEvPNSt4FILEE13format_stringIDp1TEDpRR1T). И в чем проблема указать типы?

Comment: Это как глоток свежего воздуха. Жаль, спасибо за ответ((((

Comment: Например это сделали люди, писавшие реализацию питона на С (Cython ).

Comment: На чистом Си - через макрос _Generic((X)

Comment: [Generic selection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic)

Comment: printo("text", double, float, uint(8-16-32-64)_t, int(8-16-32-64)_t )  https://github.com/AVI-crak/Rtos_cortex/blob/master/sPrint.h

Comment: [Например](https://habr.com/ru/articles/544038/), внизу ссылка на исходники. Хотя, за 20+ лет с C у меня ни разу не было такой необходимости, как раз наоборот, строгость формата `*printf` нужней.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы)))))